# Programming "Arduino" code to AT90S8515?

Tags: arduino-uno, avr, atmel-studio

I found (from a previous life) an STK500 and a couple AT90S8515's in the recesses of my basement..  that I would like to put to use.

Is there a way in which I can write "arduino code" for the 8515?  I know that it's basically C/C++.

I also know that the 8515 doesn't have, or support, a bootloader like the Mega series of ICs do..  so I expect that I will need to program it using the STK500.

I downloaded AVR Studio, but I will admit, I became very lost, very quickly.

Thanks for any direction!

Answer (score 1):

Theoretically yes, once you write a [core](https://code.google.com/p/arduino/wiki/Platforms) ([1.5.x/1.6.x](https://code.google.com/p/arduino/wiki/Platforms1)) for it. I'm not sure if the IDE has a configuration for the STK500, but it should be easy enough to add (since avrdude already supports it).

Answer (score 0):

In Atmel Studio 7 you can create a project on Arduino Code.
For instance if you have a code for an Arduino UNO, it will ask for path of the sketch(a.ino file) and ask for device here it will be Atmega 328.
Now you can build the solution and it will generate code for Atmega 328.
Now you can rebuild the same solution by changing the device now select  AT90S8515.
In my case I built the code for a Atmega328. then rebuilt it by changing device to Atmega8. It worked